# Replicated single Database in mongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I want to replicated a single database of a mongoDB-Server. There are four databases on the server:

| Server A | to replicated | Server B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| database 1a |  | database 1b |
| database 2a |  | database 2b |
| database 3a | --------------> | database 3b |
| database 4a |  | database 4b |

Only the *database 3a* should be replicated to Server B.

How can I do it? Is it possible with the normal replication configuration (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/replication/) and if the answer is yes, how?

I hope you can help. Thank you in forward.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: this is not possible with [Replication](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/replication/).

Long answer: Perhaps is would be possible with some crazy setup of a [Sharded Cluster](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/sharding/), because sharding is enabled/disabled per database.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible... [Change streaming](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/) is the solution. So, you copy changes of one database (or collection) to other server.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I write the following code, but it does not work as I imagine it:
`// Above the database connection will build.
 var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(m_collection);
        var cursor = collection.Watch();
    if (cursor.MoveNext() && cursor.Current.Count() == 0)
     {
      cursorOUTPUT = "0";
    }else{
     var next = cursor.Current.First();
    //cursorOUTPUT = next.ToString();
     cursorOUTPUT = "1";
    }
    cursor.Dispose();`
The code will execute every 10s and I only get the cursorOUTPUT "0". I hope you can help me :)

Comment: Remember that you must first create that DB and copy that collection from source (export - import) and after that you use stream to apply all changes (what will come when source collection is changed) to it.

Comment: Yes, I do it. But if I do some changes - for example an update on a collection, I only get the "0" on cursorOUTPUT.